# Autocad macro to fill an area with as many of an object as possible

Tags: autocad, cad

Is there a macro function in Autocad that fills an area with as many blocks/objects as possible given a constraint spacing between the objects?  For example: a macro to fill a room with as many chairs as possible but leaving a 30cm gap between chairs

Comment: That's still a relevant issue and I'd be interested in a solution

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality does not exist as an out-of-the-box command in AutoCAD - you would need to develop a program using one of the available APIs in AutoCAD (LISP/.NET/ObjectARX).

Comment: @elliotsvensson I don't see how Excel is related to this question?